# Return an updated list by clicking a button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a a simple Form, with a panel that holds a question with four CheckButtons as answers.
The users will go through the form and select the answer for each Question.
Once they click the button to accept the answer ("buttonNewAnswer_Click" below in the code)
the answer gets consolidated in a List named "answers" and then I write that into "results" and format it so I can write one line to a .csv file.
Once all the Questions are covered, the users will click "buttonExit_Click" button 
and that will write the "results" to the .csv and also exit the Application.
Unfortunatelly I cannot get the "results" list from the "buttonNewAnswer_Click" to "buttonExit_Click".
Thank you for your help/suggestions.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SIMPLE_FORM
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //public List<String> results = new List<String>();
    string myCsvFileTest = @"myFile.csv"


    // Button to update the answers list
        private void buttonNewAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    // Algorithm to update the "answers" list

            var results = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var i in answers)
            {
                results.AppendFormat("{0},", i.ToString());
            }
        }

    // Button to write the results to a .csv and then close the application
        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Press \"Yes\" to confirm closing the Application", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myCsvFileTest, true, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(results);  
                }
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Activate();
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to get the "results" list from the "buttonNewAnswer_Click" and use it somewhere else in the code such as "buttonExit_Click" to write to a .csv

Comment: Take the StringBuilder definition move outside of the click event so both click methods can access the variable. For example, myCsvFileTest is not in any method.  It is in global space of the Form class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `results` object as a `Form1` class member.

Right now, you are defining it as a local variable in `buttonNewAnswer_Click` function - so it's destroyed once the function ends.

Simplified code based on the code in the question:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // declare and allocate
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

    private void buttonNewAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        // fill the results object
        foreach (var i in answers)
        {
            results.AppendFormat("{0},", i.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you can use the result here.
        // results
    }   
}
```